# Retrieving deleted observations in SAS

Tags: sas

We were discussing the nobs= option of SAS today (gotcha below), and the question came up - how do you restore / retrieve deleted observations?

```
data test;
x=1;
output;
x=2;
output;
run;

proc sql;
    delete from test where x=2;
quit;

data _null_;
    set test nobs=n;
    put n=; /* gotcha */
run;
```

Comment: It appears you found a bug.  I replaced your SQL procedure with one that recreates the data set (CREATE TABLE TEST AS SELECT TEST FROM TEST WHERE X ~=2) and the result of the PUT N=; line was 1, as expected.

Comment: @RWill: not a bug, just a piece of SAS weirdness. See http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p095-26.pdf

Comment: makes sense - you would not want to rebuild a large table unnecessarily.  It shows that the metadata values cannot be relied on.  But original question remains!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the records being "marked for deletion", thus suggesting that there might be a way to "unmark for deletion", there is currently no facility to recover these records.  It's too bad as it seems like it might be useful in some cases.